# Is there a way to check if the try statement was successful or not?

Tags: python

Just started learning python and wanted to make a calculator. I currently have some code that tries to turn what the user inputs into an integer, but what I want to do is be able to check if the attempt was successful or not.

Here is the part i'm having trouble with.

```
import sys

first_number = input('Enter a number: ')

try:
  int(first_number)
except:
  print("Sorry, that's not a number.")
  exit()
```

Comment: You said you're "having trouble", but what is thr trouble with what you've tried (aside from using bare `except:`, which is almost never a good idea)?

Comment: If the line works, it will simply continue after the line.  If it reaches the except, then it continues after the except clause.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can set a flag after `int` that is only set on success:

```
success=False
nums=iter(['abc','123'])
while not success:
    try:
        x=int(next(nums))
        success=True
    except ValueError as e:
        print(e, 'Try Again!')
        
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc' Try Again!
123
```

First time with `'abc'` is an error, second time a success.

Since `nums` first try is an error, that will not set `success` to `True`. Second time is not an error, `success` is set to `True` and the `while` loop terminates. You can use the same method with user input. The iterator is just simulating that...

So for your example:

```
success=False
while not success: 
    try:
        n_string = input('Enter a number: ')
        int(n_string)
        success=True
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'"{n_string}" is not a number. Try again')
```

Which is commonly simplified into this common idiom in Python for user input:

```
while True:
    try:
        n_string = input('Enter a number: ')
        int(n_string)
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print(f'"{n_string}" is not a number. Try again')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just do:

```
try:
    int(first_number)
    print("try successful!")
except ValueError:
    print("Sorry, that's not a number.")
    print("try unsuccessful!")
    exit()
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't know how I missed that.

Answer (score -1):

To have this make more sense, make it a function:

```
def getNumber():
    while True:
        number = input('Enter a number: ')
        if number.isnumeric():
            return int(number)
        print( "Not a number, please try again." )
```